# USB connection with RICOH THETA is suddenly disconnected: THETA UVC Blender Status:0x800705AA:

Tags: python, camera, theta360, ricoh-theta

I apologize but I’m hoping someone here can help.

I have connected the THETA S to my laptop with a USB cable to acquire images on a Python program, but after a few minutes to a few dozen minutes of standing, I am unable to acquire images.

Python program

```py
import cv2

# Set device ID to 2 to get converted images from THETA.
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
while True:
  ret, image = cap.read()
  if not ret:
     break

  cv2.imshow("ok", image)
  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
     break
```

After the disconnection, this is the image that will be entered.

`THETA UVC Blender Status:0x800705AA`:

[image: 1]

Anyone can give me their opinion.

It may have something to do with the fact that the USB cable is 5 meters long, but so far we are dealing with the following on a Windows PC.

- Disable the USB selective suspend setting.
- Set the power option to High Performance.

Comment: `args` is not defined.  what is this ?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out.
I have corrected the code.

Comment: same error message found here: https://community.theta360.guide/t/theta-refuses-to-live-stream-via-usb-error-theta-uvc-blender-status-0x800705aa/54 -- if it's not the overly long third-party USB cable, then you might wanna contact Ricoh about this

Answer (score 0):

it appears as though you have basic errors with your code.

for a start `args` was never defined, so the given code throws and error on this line.

Here is a basic working script to get a camera working:

```py
import cv2

# Open the camera
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # Get a frame from the camera
    ret, frame = camera.read()

    # Display the frame
    cv2.imshow("Camera", frame)

    # Exit the loop if the 'q' key is pressed
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Release the camera and close the window
camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The above works on my `windows10` laptop with `python3.10` and latest `cv2` version.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I didn't notice the problem because I had cut out a part of the program and described it.
We will correct the question as well.

Comment: RICOH THETA cameras suggest using the original USB cable. The 5 meter-long USB cable may be causing issues.

Comment: @JesseCasman,  this could well be the case too (hardware).  The answer here was highlighting the **error in the code itself** and **correct implementation** of this (software).

Comment: @Jesse Casman
 Thank you for your response. I think that is the problem too.
As a way to deal with this, I will try the THETA original USB cable and a USB extension cable with repeater function.